# Traffic light with STM32

Tags: stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I am designing a traffic light control system with the following description:

1. When pressing button 1 (name this button rst: reset), the traffic light system immediately goes into control state (programming anti-vibration button), the green light in the North-South direction will light up, the light will turn in the opposite direction. East and West will be bright
2. When switch 1 is turned on, the yellow light in the North-South direction will light up for 3 seconds, counting down to 0 and then switching back to the red light, while the red light in the East-West direction will wait until the red light in the North-South direction appears before going back to the red light for 3 seconds. return to 0 and then switch back to green light.
3. When switch 1 is turned off, the yellow light in the East-West direction will light up for 3 seconds, counting down to 0 and then switching back to the red light, while the red light in the North-South direction will wait until the red light in the East-West direction appears before going back to the red light for 3 seconds. return to 0 and then switch back to green light.
4. When pressing the reset button, everything will return from step 2
   However, when I run the code, all 4 of my yellow lights are on and I cannot control my lights. Please help me

I tried to fix my code, I have fixed the code and programmed the anti-vibration button, but it's all in vain, Here's my code:

```
uint8_t direct = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(direct_GPIO_Port, direct_Pin);
uint8_t rst = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(rst_GPIO_Port, rst_Pin);
uint8_t i;
uint8_t j;
uint8_t pre_state = GR;
uint8_t next_state;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1){
      if (rst == 1) {
          pre_state = GR;
      } else {
          pre_state = next_state;
      }

      switch (pre_state) {
          case GR:
              if (direct == 0) {
                  next_state = GR;
              } else {
                  next_state = YR;
                  i = 3;
              }
              break;

          case YR:
              if (i != 0) {
                  next_state = YR;
                  i = i - 1;
              } else if  (i == 0){
                  pre_state = RR1;
                  next_state = RR1;
                  j = 3;
              }
              break;

          case RR1:
              if (j != 0) {
                  next_state = RR1;
                  j = j - 1;
              } else if (j == 0){
                  pre_state = RG;
                  next_state = RG;
              }
              break;

          case RG:
              if (direct == 1) {
                  next_state = RG;
              } else {
                  next_state = RY;
                  j = 3;
              }
              break;

          case RY:
              if (j != 0) {
                  next_state = RY;
                  j = j - 1;
              } else if (j == 0){
                  pre_state = RR2;
                  next_state = RR2;
                  i = 3;
              }
              break;

          case RR2:
              if (i != 0) {
                  next_state = RR2;
                  i = i - 1;
              } else if (i == 0){
                  pre_state = GR;
                  next_state = GR;
              }
              break;
      }
      if (pre_state == GR) {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          } else if (pre_state == YR) {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          } else if (pre_state == RR1) {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          } else if (pre_state == RR2) {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          } else if (pre_state == RG) {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          } else {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R1_GPIO_Port, R1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G1_GPIO_Port, G1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y1_GPIO_Port, Y1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(R2_GPIO_Port, R2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(G2_GPIO_Port, G2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Y2_GPIO_Port, Y2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the `uint8_t direct = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(direct_GPIO_Port, direct_Pin);` and `uint8_t rst = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(rst_GPIO_Port, rst_Pin);` only once and outside of your `while(1)` loop you only put the initial state of those pins in the mentioned variables.
To fix this replace the the `rst` and `direct` with `HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(...)` inside your while loop.